# Compiler support for arrays | formal parameters

Tags: arrays, parsing, compiler-construction

I was asked to implement arrays basically from scratch in a compiler which compiles a C like language (in fact the language is a strict subset of C). But I think this does not really matter for the question.

I extended the scanner and parser and everything works fine for global and local arrays (even multi-dimensional arrays). Basically I allocate 8 Byte for every entry of the array, for example arr[10] would be an allocation of 80 Byte. For addressing and assigning values I use the row major algorithm.

As mentioned before, local and global arrays work fine. However, I do not get arrays as formal parameters to work.

So for example

```
int test (int a[10]);



 int main() {
  int array[10];
  int i;
  i = 0;
  while(i < 10) {
    array[i] = i;
    i = i + 1;
  }
  return test(array);
}

int test (uint64_t a[10]) {
  return a[7];
}
```

The problem here is that the declaration of the method (first line) reserves memory for the formal parameter (which works in my implementation) on the stack. But the stack has a LIFO-structure, meaning that the variables are stored in the opposite sequence than defined.

So my

```
return a[7];
```

should return the value 7. But since on the stack the order of items is different, my values are stored this way

```
a[-9] == 0;
a[-8] == 1;
a[-7] == 2;
a[-6] == 3;
.
.
.
a[-1] == 8;
a[0] == 9;
```

If I use global or local arrays, I have the address for the beginning of the array and then increase this address by some offset to access a certain element (because that is the way data storage is implemented). On the stack it is the other way around as far as I understand the results.

My problem is that the stack grows from top to bottom, so if I have the stack pointer, the variable has to be stored above it. That means I cannot just change the sign of the memory address.

So how do I get the array elements on the right index (and not some negative indices)?

I hope the question is to some extent understandable.

Comment: Note that C does not have array parameters (it allows the syntax, somewhat confusingly, but semantically `int test(int a[10])` is completely equivalent to `int test(int* a)`), so if you really want your language to be a subset of C, you shouldn't either.

Answer (score 2):

> But the stack has a LIFO-structure, meaning that the variables are stored in the opposite sequence than defined.

That doesn't happen. The only thing that's LIFO about the call stack is the order of the stack frames, what happens within a frame is entirely up to you. In a simple language with only statically sized local variables, the memory needed for all of them together can be allocated by subtracting some constant number from the stack pointer. That allocation is undone when the function is left, which is what makes it LIFO, but there is no order imposed on variables in the block and especially not on the internal structure of those variables.